# Discord.js message collector

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to wait for a response after the initial spec command is given. The two options would be See or Change and would reply with the messages given.

```
if (command == 'spec'){
    message.channel.send("See or Change?");
    const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id == message.author.id, { time: 10000 });
    console.log(collector)
    collector.on('collect', m => {
        if (message.content == "See") {
            message.channel.send("You Want To See Someones Spec OK!");
        } else if (message.content == "Change") {
            message.channel.send("You Want To Change Your Spec OK!");
        }
    })
}
```

An error occurs instead giving me this large amount of code. THe bot starts up but after the command is given it crashes. Would love if someone helped me out since i've been stuck on this for a while.

```
MessageCollector {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    end: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function (anonymous)] }
  },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  filter: [Function (anonymous)],
  options: [Function (anonymous)],
  collected: Collection(0) [Map] {},
  ended: false,
  _timeout: null,
  _idletimeout: null,
  handleCollect: [Function: bound handleCollect] AsyncFunction,
  handleDispose: [Function: bound handleDispose] AsyncFunction,
  channel: <ref *1> TextChannel {
    type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
    guild: Guild {
      id: '886817539194249227',
      name: 'CULT OF PINIS',
      icon: '67aad2f5b83706c317be25b3d322774e',
      features: [Array],
      commands: [GuildApplicationCommandManager],
      members: [GuildMemberManager],
      channels: [GuildChannelManager],
      bans: [GuildBanManager],
      roles: [RoleManager],
      presences: PresenceManager {},
      voiceStates: [VoiceStateManager],
      stageInstances: [StageInstanceManager],
      invites: [GuildInviteManager],
      scheduledEvents: [GuildScheduledEventManager],
      available: true,
      shardId: 0,
      splash: null,
      banner: null,
      description: null,
      verificationLevel: 'NONE',
      vanityURLCode: null,
      nsfwLevel: 'DEFAULT',
      discoverySplash: null,
      memberCount: 21,
      large: false,
      premiumProgressBarEnabled: false,
      applicationId: null,
      afkTimeout: 300,
      afkChannelId: null,
      systemChannelId: '886972109383958588',
      premiumTier: 'TIER_1',
      premiumSubscriptionCount: 2,
      explicitContentFilter: 'DISABLED',
      mfaLevel: 'NONE',
      joinedTimestamp: 1640578542092,
      defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL_MESSAGES',
      systemChannelFlags: [SystemChannelFlags],
      maximumMembers: 250000,
      maximumPresences: null,
      approximateMemberCount: null,
      approximatePresenceCount: null,
      vanityURLUses: null,
      rulesChannelId: null,
      publicUpdatesChannelId: null,
      preferredLocale: 'en-US',
      ownerId: '528290518472458240',
      emojis: [GuildEmojiManager],
      stickers: [GuildStickerManager]
    },
    guildId: '886817539194249227',
    parentId: '888833493168173076',
    permissionOverwrites: PermissionOverwriteManager { channel: [Circular *1] },
    messages: MessageManager { channel: [Circular *1] },
    threads: ThreadManager { channel: [Circular *1] },
    nsfw: false,
    id: '887163660353552484',
    name: '-pinis-bot-commands-',
    rawPosition: 10,
    topic: null,
    lastMessageId: '925637522988597298',
    rateLimitPerUser: 0
  },
  received: 0,
  _handleChannelDeletion: [Function: bound _handleChannelDeletion],
  _handleThreadDeletion: [Function: bound _handleThreadDeletion],
  _handleGuildDeletion: [Function: bound _handleGuildDeletion],
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you handle the collector event (on collect) you define the message object to be called "m" and then you check "message"'s content. There is the mistake.

```js
collector.on('collect', m => {
    if (m.content == "See") {
        message.channel.send("You Want To See Someones Spec OK!");
    } else if (m.content == "Change") {
        message.channel.send("You Want To Change Your Spec OK!");
    }
})
```

But this doesn't look like a reason the bot to crash. If it still crashes it must be from something else.